# High BPSORT waits resolve after server reboot

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2022

SQL Server 2022 CU10 enterprise edition. This is a 2 node AG (sync mode) with readable secondary. The issue occurs on the primary node.

Query store enabled. Intelligent query processing features enabled.

8 CPUs

256 GB memory of which 180 GB assigned to SQL server as max memory

8 tempdb files are configured, equally sized at 10 GB each. There is no issue of Tempdb growth. Tempdb drive size is 400 GB.

Every month since applying this CU10 patch in November, we are observing that an issue occurs (atleast once a month) as explained below and gets resolved only after restarting SQL server.

**Issue:**
Some queries having ORDER BY clause seem to be never finishing (keepings running for more than 1 hour, when usually the query finished in 2 minutes). During the issue I can see tempdb usage by the query, however when same query is run after reboot or on the DEV server then the query doesn't use tempdb. There is no io/memory/cpu pressure during the issue. The only unusual thing I'm observing during the issue is high BPSORT wait type (average 450ms).

Anyone else dealt with such an issue?